# How to check if mongos connection still alive in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, v8, node-mongodb-native

Let's imagine we have Node.JS app which is connecting to the Mongos process. But suddenly Mongos failed. How our app could now about it?

```
var db = null;  
mongo.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, mydb) {
    if(err) throw err;
    db = mydb
});

..... on response we have .....
db.collection('test_collection', function(err, collection){
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, documents){
        // doing some work here
        // but if Mongos failed, we are blocked on this stage
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you not want to do the same thing that you're doing at connect, but within the function?

i.e.

```
...
collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, documents) {
   if(err) {
       throw err; //or do something equivalent.  It doesn't really matter if the connection has failed, as it will still throw an error.
   } else {
       ///continue processing
   }
  ....
```

Alternatively, if you use a 3rd party mongo manager, such as mongoose, you can do something like this globally:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + config.mongo.host + '/' + config.mongo.db);
var db = mongo.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));
```

Comment: it's amazing, but i still havn't got an error in your code. I can't understand why.

Comment: Probably it's because i launch it on Windows?

Comment: Are you even dropping into the err?  What happens if you console.log inside the `if(err)` rather than a `throw err;`?